# safari: difference with image/jpeg and img/jpg

Tags: html, safari, uri, mime-types

I encountered an interesting bug with in our web development.
Everything seems good across the browser until we checked our site on Safari on Mac OS.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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" thumbnail="ab06b0f4f155495a92e5e97f02270116">
```

I got that image tag which shows the image as data uri with a mimetype of image/jpg.

I got confused with that mimetype as to why does Chrome, IE and Firefox shows my image but it won't load the image on safari until we changed it to image/jpeg.

Anybody knows the particular reason as to why? It would also help if you can include a link for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

image/jpg is technically invalid, although it's supported in many cases as a MIME type. You should always use image/jpeg. It's a little confusing, because .jpg is a valid extension.